# how to apply many operations in different columns in spark dataframe and save them with new alias

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following `spark` dataframe

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['2017-04-01', 'A',1 , 1],
                             ['2017-04-01', 'B',2,3],
                             ['2017-04-01', 'B',3,4],
                             ['2017-04-01', 'A',5,5]], schema=['pdate', 'url', 'weight', 'imp'])
```

I would like to `groupby` `url` and do the following operations on `df` and assign the result to new columns:

- `min` of `pdate` (min_pdate as alias)
- `max` of `pdate` (max_pdate as alias)
- `sum` of `imp`   (sum_imp as alias)
- `weighted_mean` of `imp` (wmean_imp as alias)

Is there a neat way to do this using pyspark ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `agg` function to apply many functions to `groupBy`

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

from pyspark.shell import spark

df = spark.createDataFrame([['2017-03-01', 'A', 1, 1],
                            ['2017-04-01', 'B', 2, 3],
                            ['2017-05-01', 'B', 3, 4],
                            ['2017-06-01', 'A', 5, 5]], schema=['pdate', 'url', 'weight', 'imp'])

df = df \
    .groupBy(f.col('url')) \
    .agg(f.min('pdate').alias('min_pdate'),
         f.max('pdate').alias('max_pdate'),
         f.sum('imp').alias('sum_imp'),
         (f.sum(f.col('imp') * f.col('weight')) / f.sum(f.col('weight'))).alias('wmean_imp'))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----------+----------+-------+-----------------+
|url| min_pdate| max_pdate|sum_imp|        wmean_imp|
+---+----------+----------+-------+-----------------+
|  B|2017-04-01|2017-05-01|      7|              3.6|
|  A|2017-03-01|2017-06-01|      6|4.333333333333333|
+---+----------+----------+-------+-----------------+
```